# is there a way for App Branding on Apple App Store?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

My Company has a requirements for App Branding of an app. I have created a certain app `MyCompanyApp`. Now clients say that they want to see the app with their **company name** on App Store and also **app logo** must reflect client instead of my company. Is there any luck for having such branding facility on App store? or do i need to create separate apps for each client (with **separate** APP ID, certificates, Provisioning profiles, APNs certificates). which is quite lot of work to manage.

Comment: Yes, you need to create separate apps for each client, probably also separate developer accounts if they want the app to appear associated to their company only.

Comment: This is not fair then :( Why app store don't provide some facility like this?

Comment: You can charge your client for this extra trouble. Maybe that makes it fairer. From Apple's point of view they have no benefit from offering such a facility. If anything, it would make it easier to swamp the App Store with slightly different flavours of otherwise identical apps (and that cannot be in anyone's interest).

Comment: If this does not need to be on the public App Store, but is meant for use by MyCompany's own employees, the Enterprise Distribution plans are also a good alternative.

Comment: That need to be on public app store because each client want to distribute to public (but membership is not free. anyone having app can't register/use unless he is a member of the client on web portal.)  Conclusion is I need to do all the stuff by myself of managing different flavours of app.